# Async, multithreaded scraping in Python with limited threads

Tags: python, multithreading

We have to refactor scraping algorithm. To speed it up we came up to conclusion to multi-thread processes (and limit them to max 3). Generally speaking **scraping** consists of following aspects:

1. **Scraping** (async request, takes approx 2 sec)
2. Image processing  (async per image, approx 500ms per image)
3. Changing source item in DB (async request, approx 2 sec)

What I am aiming to do is to create batch of **scraping** requests and while looping through them, create a stack of consequent async operations: Process images and as soon as images are processed -> change source item.

In other words - **scraping** goes. but image processing and changing source items must be run in separate limited async threads.

Only think I don't know how to stack the batch and limit threads.

Has anyone came across the same task and what approach have you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is consumer-producer pattern. Just create 3 different queues and when you process the item in one of them, queue new work in another. Then you can 3 different threads each of them processing one queue.

Comment: Your answer lead me to this https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Producer_Consumer_using_Queue.php great stuff...